# Get Rhino JS to see Java class

Tags: java, javascript, classpath, rhino

I'm playing with [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/doc.html), and I've had success using Java classes from the stdlib, but not from Java code I compiled here.

For example, this works fine:

```
print(new java.util.Date());
```

But with [NanoHTTPD](http://elonen.iki.fi/code/nanohttpd/) (single .java file, no namespace, same folder), I'm having no luck at all:

```
js> new Packages.NanoHTTPD()
js: "<stdin>", line 4: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: TypeError: [JavaPackage NanoHTTPD] is not a function, it is object.
    at <stdin>:4
```

I'm sure it's something simple.  What am I missing?

**EDIT**: I'm launching it like this:

```
$ CLASSPATH=. java -jar rhino.jar
```

or this:

```
$ java -classpath . -jar rhino.jar
```

Or I moved NanoHTTPD.java into the folder "./nano", added `package nano;` to the top of the file, compiled it, and then replaced "." with "nano" in the above classpath assignments.

Any way I do it, from in the interpreter I see:

```
js> java.lang.System.getProperty("java.class.path")
/Users/me/blah/rhino.jar
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to run Rhino like this:

```
java -cp /path/to/rhino/js.jar:. org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main
```

This adds the current directory to the classpath.  Using `-jar` clobbers the classpath. (The classpath separator depends on your OS.)

Then try

```
js> Packages.NanoHTTPD
[JavaClass NanoHTTPD]
```

If it says `[JavaPackage NanoHTTPD]`, it means it hasn't found a class by that name.

You can't instantiate NanoHTTPD anyways, so I'm guessing you want to try `Packages.NanoHTTPD.main([])` or something.

Comment: Aah, this did the trick!  Though I'm not sure why you say I can't instantiate NanoHTTPD -- I am, and it's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

In my Linux, I found that the command 'rhino' is a shell script that runs 'org.mozilla.javascript.shell.Main' with the option '-classpath'. You can edit the file to include the path to your class. 
I think the script is self explanatory.
If you use Linux, type:

```
less `which rhino`
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't plan to use your own clases in Rhino usually you run it in following way:
`java -jar ./js.jar`
The problem to use the `-jar` switch is that you can't define `classpath` in this case and without setting `classpath` you can't access to your own packages and classes.
To be able to set `classpath` you need to run Rhino using `-cp` switch. In this case you set your `classpath` by `-cp` switch which shall include package of Rhino and your packages and also you need pass Rhino's main class path inside the package (`org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main`)
Here is an example how to add your own packages to Rhino classpath:
Suppose you have your class `mypackage.myclass` placed in `mylib.jar` If you want to get this class available in your Rhino session you need to run Rhino in following way:
`java -cp "./js.jar;../mylib.jar" org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main`
Then you can access to your class:
`jc> mc_obj = new Packages.mypackage.myclass()`

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the current directory is included in your classpath.  The default classpath is the current directory but if the classpath has been set to something else (say by the rhino startup script) then you could run into this.

You might also try placing your test class in a package just to see if it has some quirk with top-level classes.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done Java -- how do you do this?  I've tried `CLASSPATH=.` and `-cp .` (but System.getProperty("java.class.path") just has rhino.jar), and System.setProperty("java.class.path", ".") (not sure if that should work).

Comment: I've tried putting my class in a package (and compiling it), and the behavior I'm seeing is exactly the same in that case.

Comment: It's -classpath path1;path2;path3 on windows, and -classpath path1:path2:path3 on mac or linux.  Each path element is either a jar or a directory.  You can also use -cp, both options do the same thing.  How are you launching rhino?  If you're launching it with a batch file or script, you should be able to edit the script  to add the classpath you need.  And no, System.setProperty("java.class.path",...) will not work.

Comment: The comment was getting long, so I added it to the question, above.