# Rhino: Loading packages under Windows

Tags: javascript, rhino

I'm trying to load a package that's in a directory in my classpath, but something's gone wrong. What am I doing wrong here?

```
D:\temp>set CLASSPATH=D:\temp;D:\temp\rsslib4j.jar"

D:\temp>java org.mozilla.javascript.tools.shell.Main
Rhino 1.7 release 4 2012 06 18
js> importPackage(java.lang)
js> importPackage(rsslib4j.jar)
js: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: ReferenceError: "rsslib4j" is not defined.

js>  System.out.println(java.lang.System.getProperty("java.class.path"));
D:\temp;D:\temp\rsslib4j.jar"
js> quit()

D:\temp>
```

Comment: Similar question previously asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481696/get-rhino-js-to-see-java-class

Comment: @mjk Similar, yes, but what's the point of having a CLASSPATH environment variable if it's going to be ignored anyway? I'm not using -jar and it still clobbers the classpath. This only happens under Windows.